# how to change data source from select bokeh

Tags: python, plot, datasource, bokeh

I am using Bokeh and Python 2.7

Im trying to update the Data Source to change the plot based on Select Box.
But I am not able to update the plot.
what am I doing wrong? or is there a better way?

Code:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh import models
import pandas as pd

d1 = dict(x=  [10,4,6,4], y =  [6,2,8,10])

d2 = dict(x=  [23,12,50,30], y =  [5,10,23,18,12])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=d1)

p = figure()

select = Select(title="Select d",  options=['d1', 'd2'])

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    if new == 'd1':
        newSource = d1

    if new == 'd2':
        newSource = d2


    source.data =  newSource

p.line(x='x', y='y',source = source)

select.on_change('value', update_plot)
layout = column(row(select, width=400), p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
show(layout)
```

Comment: are you sure `update_plot` is triggered? Did you try calling `update_plot` directly without the on_change?

Comment: How can i verify if update_plot is triggered?
I read in bokeh documentation that is necessary 'on_change' function

Comment: can you add a `print('hello')` statement within `update_plot`?

Comment: I added it, but the script doesn't print 'hello'

Comment: indeed. I am testing myself right now. Can you try `open("/var/tmp/log.txt", "a").write("test\n")` (if you are on Windows, use e.g. C:/tmp/log.txt?)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. do you want I add that statement within update_plot?

Comment: how did you start bokeh?

Comment: I'm learning bokeh by myself, reading official documentation and forums

Comment: no I mean: do you work with the bokeh server? How do you start your script?

Comment: Ahhh ok! I started the script from reading the bokeh official documentation .. but it does not explain very clearly the interactions with the widgets. I have to generate plots from 10 sensors.. so I want to generate a "selector" like a dropdown to select the sensor and plot their frequenciesAhhh ok! I started the script from reading the bokeh official documentation .. but it does not explain very clearly the interactions with the widgets. I have to generate plots from 10 sensors.. so I want to generate a "selector" like a dropdown to select the sensor and plot their frequencies

Comment: I was able to plot 1 sensor, but they are 10 hahaha ..

Comment: your last answer works fine!! thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to start bokeh with the bokeh server, like this:

```
bokeh serve myscript.py
```

And then open `localhost:5006` in your browser.

If you start bokeh without the server then it just creates a static html file and there is no way you can either make the page call your functions (that's why you don't see the `print`s) or alter the page with your python code after the initial load. From [the docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html):

> The architecture of Bokeh is such that high-level “model objects” (representing things like plots, ranges, axes, glyphs, etc.) are created in Python, and then converted to a JSON format that is consumed by the client library, BokehJS. [...] However, if it were possible to keep the “model objects” in python and in the browser in sync with one another, then more [you could also] respond to UI and tool events generated in a browser with computations or queries using the full power of python

Comment: Addtionally (Just an FYI) `show` is not usefu inside Bokeh apps and is ignored (but you can pass `--show` to `bokeh serve` to open a browser automatically).